# Three.js Object rotation

Tags: object, rotation, center, three.js

I'm a French developper so sorry for my English.

I need to place some objects on a ground and user can rotate and move them. I've made a function that permit to mirror objects on the field. For this I had to rotate mirrored objects to fit the function and I saw that some of my objects, which I had designed with Solidworks then exported as STL then as OBJ and finally exported with convert_obj_three.py, don't rotate by there center (gravity center).

So, how can I make this work? You can see this code running at http://spyshare.fr/three. Try to add a "MiniM" by right click on the scene and rotate it with 'R' key.

Thanks for the great work ;).

Comment: That example never finished loading here... ?

Comment: @mrdoob : For me it's good, there is only a skymap and a grassground from tQuery loaded, plus 2 PlaneGeometry with wireframe on it to make a grid. Next you right click on the scene and can add an object like said in my previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my mistake. When I had designed my objects on Solidworks I haven't build them around the axis so in my .js file the vertices coords were not around 0,0,0.